# Phalcon view not rendering right from other actions

Tags: view, phalcon

I was reading the documentation on Phalcon about Hierarchical Rendering("http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/views.html#hierarchical-rendering"). And I can't seem to figure it out. I have the following file setup just like the documentation but the only difference is that i am using volt.

```
--views
  --vacancy
      --index.volt// action
      --new.volt//action
  --layouts
    --vacancy.volt//controller
```

And this is my Vacancy controller. It's just an empty controller

```
class VacancyController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
    public function newAction()
    {

    }
}
```

**Problem**
When i go to "mysite.com/vacancy" everything seems to be rendering just fine. But when i use the "new" action "mysite.com/vacancy/new"  i get the content of the file new.volt but it doesn't render the way i think it's supposed too.

In the chrome console i get this error:

*Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:*

If i remove the action "new " it will just renders fine!
I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: Put the code of `new.volt` in the question please.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `new.volt` file?

Comment: It doesn't have anything relevant i think.. "new vacancy" it's just that string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it just by putting a / before every file that i was including into the html document..

### Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```